# Best way to deploy a script to make changes to OTHER users's Google Calendar if I have calendarIDs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have a sheets-bound script at the moment that reads the spreadsheet data and creates calendar events based on the sheet. That spreadsheet also stores other user's calendarIDs (not owned by me) for which I am trying to read/write their google calendar's.

My ideal usage flow was that a single user could trigger the script for all stored users OR each user could click on the script and have their events added to their specified calendar but I found that I am unable to even access other's calendars with just their calendarIDs.

My code was crashing earlier after I created a test calendar on a different google account. I toggled the calendar to public and am now at least getting null as indicated by the [getEvents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app?hl=pt-BR#getcalendarbyidid) documentation. I then subscribed to that calendar and received "exception: Action not allowed".

I have come across [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) and feel like this is something I need to somehow implement but I was not sure how to go about it. **Am I able to make changes to multiple usere's calendars from the script or do I need to learn about webapps and would that allow me to somehow access other's calendars?**

**Edit**: I'm not a domain user, just using private personal google accounts

**Edit 2**: Also found out add-ons are a thing. Going to read about that

```js
/**
Function to add shift details to user's calendar
@param{object} user-object with keys of column header's of user-info sheet 
(name, email, year, calName, calID, early, late)
@param{object} eventDetails - an object with keys created after interpreting shift codes 
(title, start, end, location, desscription, problem, pdate, pvalue)
*/
function addToCalendar(user, eventDetails){
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(user.calID);
  if(calendar == null){
    Logger.log(user.name); //testing code, realized I couldn't accesss other's calIDs here
  }
  var existingEvents = calendar.getEvents(eventDetails.start, eventDetails.end);
  if(existingEvents.length>0){
    if(existingEvents[0].getTitle() == eventDetails.title){
      Logger.log("ALREADY CREATED!!");
      return;
    }
  }
  calendar.createEvent(eventDetails.title, eventDetails.start, eventDetails.end, 
                       {description : (eventDetails.description ? eventDetails.description:""),
                        location: (eventDetails.location ? eventDetails.location:"")});
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a nice way to avoid coding OAuth flows into you app, is to deploy the script as a [Web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and deploy it with the option to **"Execute the app as: User accessing the web app"**.

When the user makes a request from your webapp, your web app's consent screen pops up, and user must give consent, after this, this script runs as the user and can add the events to their calendars using the CalendarApp.

Comment: Some added features in my script is it currently sends an email based on the spreadsheet values. Would that be something I could still incorporate within a webapp? 

Reading a spreadsheet, making changes to a calendar, and email informing user of script's outcomes

Comment: You can use all of the Apps Script services within your script. Please remember the guidelines, if [someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)